# Let $ n,m \in Z$. Prove the following: If $m$ and $n$ are even, then so is $mn.$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

Question: Let $ n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove the following:

$\forall$$(m \wedge n)$, if both $m$ and $n$ are even, then so is $mn.$

Attempt: By Definition 2.3.1, we let $ n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, $n$ is even whenever there exists some $ k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ n = 2k$ and $n$ is odd whenever there exists some $ k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n = 2k+1$

Suppose $m$ and $n$ are even, then there exists some $ k \in \mathbb{Z}$ [and $l \in \mathbb{Z}$] such that $ m = 2l$ and $n = 2k$.

For, $mn$, we have

$(2k)(2l)$

My question is whether or not I should just stop there or go further.

So I could just continue by multiplying the $2$

$(4kl)$

and then manipulate a bit?

$(2)(2kl)$

As a result $mn$ is  even.

Comment: Yep that's good.

Comment: woo hoo... but I still don't know if I should just stop at $(2k)(2l)$ or manipulate by multiplying the $2$ to make it $(4kl)$ and then.. take a $2$ out like $(2)(2kl)$?!

Comment: You should go as further as your last line. This is an exercise to mess with the definitions and such such you should present the final answer with the same looks as the definition. You forgot to mention what $l$ is and to quantify it. Otherwise it is fine. After your last line, I'd conclude with "Thus, by definition, $mn$ is even".

Comment: oh yeah I thought so... if I just stop at that I know something is wrong already. So the goal of this is to have a final answer that is the same as the definition. so If I have an even, I should have something similar to $ n =2k$ Oh! I should've put there also exists some $ l \in Z$. 

and then for the last part... As a result, $mn$ is even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never hurts to provide more detail as long as it is pertinent to the proof.

I would have finished it off as follows:
$$mn = (2k)(2l) = 4(kl) =2(2kl)$$
and as $2kl\in \mathbb{Z}$, it is a witness to the conclusion that $mn$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have it.  Using modular arithmetic to condense the argument, suppose $n \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$ and $m \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$. Then we have:

$$nm \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$$

by properties of modular arithmetic.  In general, if $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ and $x \equiv y \pmod{n}$, then $ax \equiv by \pmod{n}$.  It's a good exercise to prove this :)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly clearer to use the associative property to rearrange the parentheses:
$$(2k)(2l) = (2)(k2l)$$
and $k2l$ is an integer because $k$, $2$, and $l$ are.